# Using DateTime With input from a textbox.text

Tags: c#, datetime, parameters

I have this code that when executed gives me 74 Days, which is correct, but the date for `oldDate` has to come from a `TextBox`.  Does anyone know how to do this as the `DateTime` only takes three integers.

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     string  myDate = myTextBox.Text;

     DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(2013, 6, 5);

     DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;

     // Difference in days, hours, and minutes.
     TimeSpan ts = oldDate - newDate;
     // Difference in days.
     int differenceInDays = ts.Days;

     differenceInDays = ts.Days;

     myTextBlock.Text = differenceInDays.ToString();        
}
```

Comment: Is the user entering a date in the TextBox?  If so you could use `oldDate = DateTime.Parse(myTextBox.Text)`.

Comment: Agreed.. or if you want them to have separate fields and bunch together.. eack textbox can be MonthTextBox.Text = Convert.ToInt32(stringvalue)

Comment: Thank you for your time Martin works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the date from the user:

```
string  myDate = myTextBox.Text;

DateTime oldDate;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(myDate, out oldDate))
{
   // User entered invalid date - handle this
}

// oldDate is set now
```

That being said, depending on the UI framework, a more appropriate control (ie: the [`DateTimePicker`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker&referringTitle=Home) from the extended WPF toolkit, etc) may be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

From your code you have to obtain oldDate from myTextBox, which you have stored in myDate string variable. You can convert it to datetime

```
oldDate=Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);
```

But since it might cause exception use following

```
`DateTime myyDateTime;if(DateTime.TryParse(myDate, out myDateTime){//use your date difference code here}
```